# Blender for Criminalistic

Tags: modeling

is there any tool in blender for Criminalistic analysis?
Modeling a body, see the trajectory of a bullet, etc. 
I have seen rigs, and it's very useful but maybe there is a specific tool for this purpose. 
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly the purpose is? To show or to simulate? Modeling aspects are surely well covered by the software. Could you tell a bit more about what you expect?

Comment: @Carlo I think if blender covers realistic physics, then the above could be achieved...but it would take a lot of effort

Comment: I would not trust blender's physics for a task like this.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise against any serious use other than for the purpose of visualization - you can:

- create 3D portrait of suspects
- where and how the body fell with rag-doll physics
- how a skull was fractured when hit by axe
- where did fire or liquids hit the skin
- reflections in mirrors or windows
- etc.

But these simulations are not driven with real exact physics, they are only approximations and just based on them (simplified for performance) and cannot be used seriously for analysis, they are for shows. In some cases it can give approximate results, but in others there is no assurance that the result would'n be far from reality.

It's the other way around - you need analysis (or some reference) based on which you create the visual. Blender software has tools to match what you want visually.

It is a great tool to show others what you need, so they don't have to rely on imagination, but generally Blender tools lack accuracy to have merit in serious criminalistic proofing.

In cases where Blender is close to reality (as it should be for the visuals to feel believable) you will deduce the same with common knowledge and there won't be any need for such analysis.